# Bitmessage as basis for open-source alternative to WhatsApp?

Tags: android, ios, open-source, whatsapp, blockchain

Is it possible to use [Bitmessage](http://www.bitmessage.org) as basis for an open-source alternative to WhatsApp?

Answer (score -1):

The following links might be useful for you. I do not know anything about this topic.

- https://whispersystems.org/blog/facebook-messenger/
- https://github.com/whispersystems/

Comment: That's very interesting. Thank you!